# Free web-service for syncing cloud providers

Tags: gratis, file-synchronization, cloud-service, google-drive, dropbox

I am seeking a web-service that allows seamless file transfer (syncing is highly appreciated) between different cloud platforms, like Google Drive, OneDrive, MEGA, etc.
What I've tried so far:

1. [MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com/price). This is what I am using now, but it has free traffic limitation of 2Tb, which is quite enough for one-time transfer, but is not sufficient for regular syncing.
2. [Mover](https://mover.io/). Didn't try because it costs crazy bucks :)

I can sacrifice any feature and have no particular requirements except gratis:) Do somebody can recommend free alternative?